# How can I filter the queryset I use in my ModelChoiceField field?

Tags: django

I have looked at several answers on SO but I haven't found one that address my particular case.
I have this ModelForm which I am using in Django admin panel.

```
class AssignInventoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = []

    template = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ItemTemplate.objects.all(), 
                                      empty_label="(Select Template)")

    template.label = 'Template'

    def save(self, driver):
        driver = self.form_action(driver)
        return driver
```

I would like to be able to filter `ItemTemplate` like so:

```
ItemTemplate.objects.filter(id=driver.item.id)
```

But obviously driver is not defined at that point of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer from here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/questions/2017/03/22/how-to-dynamically-filter-modelchoices-queryset-in-a-modelform.html

Here's what I had to change in my code.

In my admin class, DriverAdmin my proccess_action method now starts out like this:

```
  
   def process_action(self, request, driver_uid, action_form, action_title):
        driver = self.get_object(request, driver_uid)
        if request.method != 'POST':
            # Added drive as parameter to action_form.
            form = action_form(driver)
        else:
            # Added drive as parameter to action_form BEFORE request.POST
            form = action_form(driver, request.POST)
        ... rest of method unchanged ...
```

In my `AssignInventoryForm()` class I added this `__init__()` method.

```
   def __init__(self, driver, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AssignInventoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['template'].queryset = ItemTemplate.objects.filter(id=driver.item.id)
```